# Execution of browser default actions of simulated DOM events

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I have some code which triggers/simulates DOM events via the DOM API (createEvent, initEvent, dispatchEvent, etc.). For most DOM events such as click there is a browser default action like following a link.

Since JavaScript code execution is single threaded I´m not sure how the execution flow is when my code triggers multiple events in a batch. So let´s say I do this (pseudo code):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var event = document.body.createEvent('MouseEvent');
  event.initMouseEvent(...);
  document.body.dispatchEvent(event); 
}
```

What will happen? Is my loop first executed completely and after that all events are processed causing the default browser action to trigger and registered event listeners to execute? Or is the code execution interrupted every time dispatchEvent is called to trigger the default action (and the event listeners)?

Thanks

Comment: Events are blocking in javascript. Each iteration will block to fire the event and then continue looping

Comment: Does this mean that the browser default action will also be executed immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because JS is not multithreaded, each time an event is dispatched it will fire immediately - implementations do not create some queue of events to be fired off at the next cycle.

This is one of the reason the old [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Mutation_events) have been deprecated. For example, if you add 400 elements to a node, it will fire 400 mutation events (which propagate) slowing down the pretty much everything.

So in your code snippet, every iteration of your loop will create the mouse event, dispatch the mouse event, handle all listeners of the mouse event and then proceed to execute the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I created a code example where one can see what you explained. However I´m more concerned about the browser default action. You can see here http://jsbin.com/AGUCuMAf/2/edit?html,js,console,output that only after dispatching all 100 events the browser actually jumps to that anchor. However since it already executes all associated listeners every time a event is dispatched I would expect it to immediately follow the anchor.

Comment: I believe thats a result of the browser "hanging" as it runs your loop. The loop takes a long time to finish and since js only has one stack, DOM updates will occur only on the next cycle unless you have some explicit code to start the reflow.

Comment: Actually the example is not working correctly. I´m trying to fix it now. But what you mention is what I was initially talking about. There is only one thread for code execution (in this case the for loop and all potential event listeners) and the browser GUI (the browser default actions, in the example the jumping to the anchor). If events are fired immediately and attached listeners are also executed straight away it would be a bit weird to wait with the browser default action until the for loop is finished, wouldn´t it?

Comment: The browser (default) action is invoked on each loop but afaik it wont actually run until the thread has time (see `setImmediate` or `setTimeout(fn, 0)`). I think the DOM will try to update the view (ie scroll to #below) after it finishes processing your code.

Comment: Okay so the only browser (default) action I could get working with synthetic DOM events was the one to follow the href of a clicked link: http://jsbin.com/AGUCuMAf/5/edit?html,js,console,output Also the example will only run once without reloading the page because the iframe leaves the sandbox. If the browser action would be executed immediately one would only see one event logged.

Comment: However I don´t understand what you mean by "The browser (default) action is invoked on each loop but afaik it wont actually run...". What is the difference between invoking and running? I think you are right by saying the thread waits until it has the time to execute. This would mean that the event dispatch is done synchronously but the according browser (default) action is put onto the execution queue (like a timeout or an interval).

Comment: Sorry but I think you got the gist; what I believe is happening is when the click event is fired the browsers registers default handler for the event, ie click the element, but it actually defers most of the work until the browser "has time" ie placed on a timeout